# Perform search query in Outlook

Tags: c#, search, outlook

Hello I am wondering if it is possible to send a search query to Outlook 2010 from my WinForms app. That is, not search the .PST file as I've been searching around and finding, I'm trying to display a list of results in Outlook as if I typed in the search box myself.

If it is possible, any example code would be helpful. Additionally, is it possible to directly perform a search in All Mail Items versus, usually when you do a search it combs the current folder. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to access the Outlook data (mail for example) you have to add a COM reference to the Microsoft Outlook X.X Object library.

For Outlook you can use COM interop. Open the Add Reference dialog and select the .NET tab, then add a reference to the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook assembly.

[image]

Afterwards don't forget to add the namespace "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" to your using clauses.

Now you can create an instance of the Outlook application object:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlook;
outlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
```

Let's perform a query on your inbox:

```
MAPIFolder folder =
    outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    IEnumerable<MailItem> mail = 
        folder.Items.OfType<MailItem>().Where(m => m.Subject == "Test").Select(m => m);
```

You specify the folder you want to search as a parameter for the GetDefaultFolder(...) method. You can specify other folder besides the inbox.

- olFolderSentMail
- olFolderOutbox
- olFolderJunk
- ...

Check out each possible value on MSDN:

[OlDefaultFolders Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff861868.aspx)

Stefan Cruysbergs created an [OutlookProvider component](http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET05&Lang=NL) which acts as a wrapper for the Outlook application object. You can use LINQ to query this provider and retrieve data such as the contacts, mail...etc.. Just [download](http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=DownloadNETOfficeItems&Lang=NL) his code and check it out. This should be enough to get you started.

Comment: hmm this is not quite what I was hoping for. I'm familiar with creating an instance of Outlook, this appears to return back to the application the results of the query. Instead, I would like to simply have Outlook open, provide a search query from my app, and in the open instance (or if not open, start Outlook) show the search results from the provided query.

Comment: Sounds like you would like to do an instant search (I know, I'm 6 years too late). You can open up outlook and automatically populate the instant search field (however it is limited to 255 characters lol). Look into this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff424478.aspx