# How to generate a reply message to an outlook email in C# where the replied to email is found based on part of it's subject line

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I have made a C# program that lets me fill in blanks to an email template that then writes the email to send. I need it to instead write this email as a reply to a certain email in an outlook subfolder that can be uniquely identified by a part of it's subject line.

I have already created the email to send using `Microsoft.Office.Interloop.Outlook.Application`

```
string s = "";
OutlookApp outlookApp = new OutlookApp();
MailItem mailItem = outlookApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
mailItem.To = "email";
mailItem.CC = "email";
mailItem.Subject = $"RE: Bulk Error {bulkNo}";
s = $"<html><body>Bulk Number: &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; {bulkNo}<br />"
    + $"Account Number: &emsp; &emsp; {acntNo}<br />" 
    + $"Policy Number: &emsp; &emsp; &ensp; &nbsp; {polNo}<br />" 
    + $"Trans Type: &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; {transType}<br />"
    + $"LOB: &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &nbsp; {lob}<br />"
    + $"Form Number: &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; {formNo}<br />"
    + $"Error: &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; {error}<br />"
    + $"Root Cause: &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &ensp; &nbsp; {rootCause}<br />"
    + $"XML Status: &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &ensp; {xmlStatus}</body></html>"
    + ReadSignature();
mailItem.HTMLBody = s;
mailItem.Display();
```

The current result is just a new email. I'm trying to get it to be a response to an existing email.

My biggest issues are that I don't know how to

1. make this message a reply

or

2. How to identify the email i want to reply to.

Comment: For 1) find the MailItem you want and [Reply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.reply(method)), For 2) use the [Application.AdvancedSearch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.advancedsearch)

Comment: I found advanced search. I'm just unsure how to use it to find what i need

Comment: There are already some examples: [Using AdvancedSearch for Outlook with C# Returns Zero Results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40867024/205233) **or** [Perform search query in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11160610/205233)

Answer (score 1):

Call `MailItem.Reply` - it will returns a new `MailItem` object with the body and recipients properly populated. You can then merge the new message body (whcih includes the old body and the header) with your new body.

To retrieve the currently selected message in Outlook, use Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection[1]. If you need to find the message first, retreive its parent folder (you can use `Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)` in case of the Inbox folder) and use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict` (where Items comes from the `MAPIFolder.Items` collection).

Comment: What's a MAPIFolder? Is it used by adding it to the top "using" list?

Comment: MAPIFolder is the object you will get back from calling Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolder?view=outlook-pia